Systematically clip a large point cloud file into smaller ones for further processing
I have a large .las point cloud file that I want to process using the lidR package in R. Since the file is too large to process at once, and R eventually crashes, I have to clip/subset my file into smaller files first.
Is there a way to do this systematically?
Basically do it in such a way, so that if I combine the clipped files later, then I will get my original .las file.

Yes use a LAScatalog and use opt_chunk_size(). Because you do not provide more details I can't be more specific.

@JRR Thanks for the advice. Is there any sample code on how to use opt_chunk_size() with a .las file as input? What additional details do you need?

See the book chapters https://r-lidar.github.io/lidRbook/engine.html. Also read the  official documentation ?LAScatalog-class

@JRR Thanks, but the link you sent is already a step forward from where I am now. I don't have a LASCatalog yet, but want to create one from a larger las file.

I don't know where you are. You provided literally 0 information about what you are doing and what you want to achieve.

@JRR Where I am is simply a large .las (ALS lidar) file that cannot be processed by R due to its size. What I want to achieve is to clip this file into smaller ones, in a systematic way, so as not to lose any point clouds. Not sure what additional information you need (?) I've described my question as clearly as possible in my initial post.

So my answer remains the same. Reads the document of the LAScatalog. There are 2 chapters dedicated to the LAScatalog engine in the book + the official documentation. opt_chunk_size() is what you are looking for.

The easiest way to deal with large LiDAR files is to tile it in smaller files. PDAL is a point cloud library that provides such tools.
Install following the quick start guide.
Once installed use the command line :
pdal tile --length 500 -i path/to/lasfile.las -o path/to/TileDirectory/tile_#.las

Change the lenght of the tile accordingly.

Thanks a lot for the suggestion! It works with PDAL. Alternatively, and with no coding required, it's possible to clip a point cloud using CloudCompare.
